# How to change the currency from USD $ to MYR in script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

I'm trying to set an automated invoice in a google spreadsheet. however, the coding on subtotal `setNumberFormat("$#,###.00")` will show the figure in USD$, how can I modify the coding to MYR currency?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve] including the regional setting of your spreadsheet and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Try setNumberFormat("MYR#,###.00") or setNumberFormat("RM#,###.00"). The RM (RInggit Malaysia) is used as a prefix but MYR (Malaysian RInggit) is used more during international transactions. Both mean the same currency. You can also make much wider localization changes by changing your code locale or even Windows localization settings.